# How do you remove a Kwikset keyed latch

Tags: lock

I have been trying everything the internet wants me to try to remove this lock. I've stuck a hex bit inside the little hex thing in the picture below and spun in every direction and still the handle won't come off.

I've tried putting the key in and turning slightly past the normal spot.

And I've tried prying the backing plate off as far as it can go in hopes of finding some sort of hidden "catch" or latch or some other item.

The lock will not come off.

Any thoughts on what I can try next?

[image: Inside of lock]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why the grub screws don't help you get the handles off... maybe they're stripped?

But you should be able to pry the interior backing plate (rosette) off and get access to screws underneath. If the handles aren't off and the plate doesn't come off all the way, it'll be awkward.

Comment: Yeah, they must have been stripped or something. I was able to use a screwdriver and pliers to bend the backing plate away enough that I could get at the screws. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

1. Loosen the set screws.
2. Pull handle off (may have to tap or wiggle handle to get it to come off).
3. Use a flathead screwdriver to pry the  escutcheon (rose, rosette) off (pry right near the dimple, to release the rose).
4. Once free, slide the escutcheon off.
5. Remove the screws that were hidden.

[image]

Comment: 1025 words... upvoted.

Comment: Wow! I learned a new word today "escutcheon". Thanks Tester

Comment: Thanks for the great pictures! I wound up having to bend the "estucheon" to get at the screws.